# 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure

Tags: smtp, sasl

Having a problem setting up authentication with smtp on my mail server using postfix. I have set up a test user inside of sasl_passwd file with info test:testpass. The same result is obtain when running AUTH LOGIN also.

```
220 rossiscloud.co.uk ESMTP Postfix
ehlo rossiscloud.co.uk
250-rossiscloud.co.uk
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 NTLM PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 NTLM PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
AUTH PLAIN dGVzdAB0ZXN0AHRlc3RwYXNz
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
```

Logs:

```
Feb  3 22:45:31 rossiscloud postfix/smtpd[8189]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Feb  3 22:45:31 rossiscloud postfix/smtpd[8189]: warning: rossiscloud.co.uk[192.168.0.200]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Feb  3 22:45:36 rossiscloud postfix/smtpd[8189]: disconnect from rossiscloud.co.uk[192.168.0.200]
```

main.cf

```
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/rossiscloud.co.uk/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/rossiscloud.co.uk/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   permit_mynetworks,
   check_relay_domains
```